# I have an issue with recursive minmaxi function (well two functions) in a chess program

Tags: c++, class, vector, chess, minimax

My recursive functions should be testing moves from black_move_list for b_maxi and white_move_list for maxi, but the program is returning '#' 7 1 -> 7 3, for example, which means 'space' from 'h2 to h4.' Despite this, the move list generated in the same function call does not contain this move. All of the function calls pass the position class by value, not reference, so I don't see how the recursive calls could modify the higher level move list. The move list is contained in a vector, but that shouldn't make any difference as far as I know. Does anyone see a glaring error in my code? (Please ignore the desperate debug attempt outputs).

Here is my main.cpp code:

```
//chess engine 2.0

#include <iostream>
#include "position.h"
#include "evaluate.h"

using namespace std;

int maxi(position board1, int depth);
int b_maxi(position board1, int depth);

move_params best_white_move;
move_params best_black_move;

const bool CLEAR        = 1;
const bool DO_NOT_CLEAR = 0;
const bool WHITE        = 1;
const bool BLACK        = 0;

const int DEPTH         = 3;

int input = 42;

int main()
{
    position test_game;
    evaluate evaluator;
    int col1, row1, col2, row2;
    while(input != 10){
        cout << "Enter a command: \n"
             << "0 (print board)\n"
             << "1 (find legal white moves)\n"
             << "2 (find legal black moves)\n"
             << "3 (print white move list)\n"
             << "4 (print black move list)\n"
             << "5 (piece move)\n"
             << "6 (evaluate position for white)\n"
             << "7 (evaluate position for black)\n"
             << "8 (find best white move)\n"
             << "10 (exit program)\n";
        cin >> input;
        switch(input){
            case 0:
                test_game.print_board();
                break;
            case 1:
                test_game.find_legal_moves(WHITE);
                break;
            case 2:
                test_game.find_legal_moves(BLACK);
                break;
            case 3:
                test_game.print_move_list('w');
                break;
            case 4:
                test_game.print_move_list('b');
                break;  
            case 5:
                cout << "Piece move. Enter col, row, new_col new_row:\n";
                cin >> col1 >> row1 >> col2 >> row2;
                test_game.move(col1,row1,col2,row2, CLEAR);
                break;
            case 6: 
                cout << "Evaluating the position for white...\n";
                cout << "score = " << evaluator.evaluate_position(test_game,WHITE) << endl;
                break;
            case 7: 
                cout << "Evaluating the position for black...\n";
                cout << "score = " << evaluator.evaluate_position(test_game,BLACK) << endl;
                break;
            case 8:
                cout << "Finding best move for white...\n";
                cout << "estimated move value: " << maxi(test_game, DEPTH) << endl;
                cout << "piece: " << best_white_move.piece << endl;
                cout << "new col: " << best_white_move.new_col << endl;
                cout << "new row: " << best_white_move.new_row << endl;
                cout << "old col: " << best_white_move.col << endl;
                cout << "old row: " << best_white_move.row << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int maxi(position board1, int depth){
    int score = 0;
    evaluate evaluator;
    if(depth == 0) return evaluator.evaluate_position(board1, WHITE);
    int max = -109009000;
    //cout << "max initialized to " << max << endl; //DEBUG
    board1.find_legal_moves(WHITE);
    for(int i = 0; i < board1.white_move_list.size();i++){
                int new_row = board1.white_move_list[i].new_row;
                int new_col = board1.white_move_list[i].new_col;
                int old_row = board1.white_move_list[i].row;
                int old_col = board1.white_move_list[i].col;
                char temp_piece = board1.board[new_col][new_row];
                //now move,

                //DEBUG ZONE BEGIN - before move
                bool next_check = false;//debugdebug
                if(depth == DEPTH-2 && board1.board[old_col][old_row] == '#'){
                    board1.print_move_list('w');
                    cout << "before move\n";
                    cout << "piece: " << board1.board[old_col][old_row] << "\n"; //DEBUG
                            cout << "move coords: " << old_col << " " << old_row 
                                 << "->" << new_col << " " << new_row << "\n"; //DEBUG          
                            cout << "depth == " << depth << "\n";//DEBUG
                            board1.print_board();//DEBUG
                }

                board1.move(old_col,old_row,new_col,new_row, DO_NOT_CLEAR);

                //DEBUG ZONE BEGIN - before b_max,but after move 
                if(depth == DEPTH-2 && board1.board[new_col][new_row] == '#'){
                    cout << "before b_max\n";
                    cout << "piece: " << board1.board[new_col][new_row] << "\n"; //DEBUG
                            cout << "max move coords: " << old_col << " " << old_row 
                                 << "->" << new_col << " " << new_row << "\n"; //DEBUG          
                            cout << "depth == " << depth << "\n";//DEBUG
                            board1.print_board();//DEBUG
                }

                //call b_maxi,
                score = -b_maxi(board1, depth - 1);

                //DEBUG ZONE BEGIN - after_bmaxi
                if(depth == DEPTH-2 && board1.board[new_col][new_row] == '#'){
                    cout << "after_bmaxi";
                    cout << "piece: " << board1.board[new_col][new_row] << "\n"; //DEBUG
                            cout << "max move coords: " << old_col << " " << old_row 
                                 << "->" << new_col << " " << new_row << "\n"; //DEBUG          
                            cout << "depth == " << depth << " & score == " << score << "\n";//DEBUG
                            board1.print_board();//DEBUG
                            next_check = true;
                }
                //DEBUG ZONE END

                //update score and GLOBAL best white move if in main depth,
                if(score > max){
                    max = score;
                    if(depth == DEPTH){
                        best_white_move.piece = board1.board[new_col][new_row];
                        best_white_move.col   = old_col;
                        best_white_move.row   = old_row;
                        best_white_move.new_col = new_col;
                        best_white_move.new_row = new_row;
                    }
                }
                if(depth == DEPTH-2){
                    //cout << "new max = " << max << "\n\n";//DEBUG
                    //cout << "\n\nspace\n\n";//DEBUG
                }

                //and unmove
                board1.board[old_col][old_row] = board1.board[new_col][new_row];
                board1.board[new_col][new_row] = temp_piece;

                //DEBUG
                if(next_check){
                    cout << "board after 'unmove':\n";
                    board1.print_board();
                    cout << "\n\n";
                }
    }
    return max;
}

int b_maxi(position board1, int depth){
    int score = 0;
    evaluate evaluator;
    if(depth == 0){ 
        int ret_val = evaluator.evaluate_position(board1, BLACK);
        //cout << "return val from mini = " << ret_val << "\n\n";
        return ret_val;
    }
    int max = -109000900;
    board1.find_legal_moves(BLACK);
    for(int i = 0; i < board1.black_move_list.size();i++){
        int new_row = board1.black_move_list[i].new_row;
        int new_col = board1.black_move_list[i].new_col;
        int old_row = board1.black_move_list[i].row;
        int old_col = board1.black_move_list[i].col;
        char temp_piece = board1.board[new_col][new_row];
        //now move,
        board1.move(old_col,old_row,new_col,new_row, DO_NOT_CLEAR);
        //call maxi,
        //cout << "depth = " << depth << ", " << "new min board: " << "\n\n"; //DEBUG
        //board1.print_board();//DEBUG
        //cout << "\n\n";//DEBUG
        score = -maxi(board1, depth - 1);

        /*DEBUG ZONE BEGIN
        if(depth == DEPTH-1){
            cout << "piece: " << board1.board[new_col][new_row] << "\n"; //DEBUG
                    cout << "B_max move coords: " << old_col << " " << old_row 
                         << "->" << new_col << " " << new_row << "\n"; //DEBUG          
                    cout << "depth == " << depth << " & score == " << score << "\n";//DEBUG
                    board1.print_board();//DEBUG
        }
        //DEBUG ZONE END*/

        //cout << "mini, depth = " << depth << "score after maxi call = " << score << "\n\n";//DEBUG
        //update score and GLOBAL best black move,
        if(score > max){
            max = score;
            if(depth == DEPTH){
                best_black_move.piece = board1.board[new_col][new_row];
                best_black_move.col   = old_col;
                best_black_move.row   = old_row;
                best_black_move.new_col = new_col;
                best_black_move.new_row = new_row;
            }
        }
        if(depth == DEPTH-1){
            //cout << "new B_max = " << max << "\n";//DEBUG
            //cout << "\n\nspace\n\n";//DEBUG
        }

        //and unmove
        board1.board[old_col][old_row] = board1.board[new_col][new_row];
        board1.board[new_col][new_row] = temp_piece;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: A lot of code but still not complete... Do you expect somebody here to debug it for you? Do you know how to use a debugger yourself?  This would be a good moment to learn. And/or unit testing.

Comment: I only expect someone here to debug it for me if there is an obvious mistake they notice. I haven't used a C++ debugger before. Is there a specific one you would recommend (using a Mac OS X)? I have done a lot of unit testing (manually).

Comment: [This](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a canonical answer. I don't know about C++ debuggers, but usually they offer the same basic feature set.

Comment: Thank you, Holterman. I stepped through the program with gdb, and next time that will definitely be my first solution before coming to stackoverflow. After some more organized unit testing, it turns out I just wasn't clearing the move lists when I called the function recursively so moves from the first ply were still analyzed. Thanks for the link! Sorry about the bush league question.

Comment: You don't have to apologize but watch the View count for this page, you weren't going to get a lot of help. Adding a language tag is usually a good idea. Leave this open, deleting questions isn't  a good plan.